# SQL MATCH/AGAINST word order

Tags: mysql, match-against

When does word order count in a query using SQL's MATCH/AGAINST feature?

Say I'm looking for someone who's name ressembles Palwinder Singh, using the following code:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT id,name,surname FROM person 
  WHERE MATCH(name,surname) 
  AGAINST('+Palwinder+Singh' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This code returns correctly the information related to someone called Palwinder Singh (who happens to be unique in my database) (this is the expected result)

However, if I use the following code:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT id,name,surname FROM person 
  WHERE MATCH(name,surname) 
  AGAINST('+Singh+Palwinder' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get a list of all players with the surname 'Singh' (22 people in all), seemingly ignoring the fact that I'm looking for Palwinder Singh.

I don't understand why the result is different? How can I get the query to be indifferent to word order?

Comment: Is this really SQL SERVER never heard of MATCH AGAINST clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use space between keywords like

```
AGAINST('+Singh +Palwinder' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I think when we use '+Singh+Palwinder', it searches fields having string like 'Singh+Palwinder'.
But when we use '+Singh +Palwinder', the search is done for both 'Singh' and 'Palwinder' in specified fields.

Comment: Thanks for this, I would have thought that the + operator would have been sufficient for it to detect two words though ?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just simply do something like ...

```
SELECT id
       ,name
       ,surname 
FROM person 
WHERE name = 'Palwinder'
AND   surname = 'Singh'
```

Comment: because I'm not actually sure that the user will have entered the name in the correct format. This code is used to import a stat sheet  that a user has filled out and that doesn't have any guidelines to fill out. Some people enter First Name, Last Name, others Last Name, First Name, and some people give the first name with the first initial of the last name and others the first initial of the first name with the last name (and not necessarily in that order !)

Comment: actually all the sheets that I'll use will have that problem, so I'm trying to work with it by doing a search based on what the user entered. If the search returns one result, I'll assume that the user wanted to refer to that person, otherwise the system returns an error and allows the user to choose from a list.